# Is it possible to compile a LibGDX game for HTML if it uses Socket.IO? If so, how?

Tags: javascript, java, gwt, socket.io, libgdx

From [what I've seen](https://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=27274), it seems to use socket.io in my game and have it run, I would need to do a lot of work to wrap JS code for Java and other things that currently fall outside my field of expertise.

Should I try to learn and do this proposed solution? Is it supposed to work by default and I'm just not doing something right? Is there an alternative to Socket.IO that I could use and implement without having to change too much of my code base?

---

If you want the more specific issue , the following error happens during task "draftCompileGwt":

```
> Task :html:draftCompileGwt
Loading inherited module 'com.lab.guy.GdxDefinitionSuperdev'
  Loading inherited module 'io.socket'
   [ERROR] Unable to find 'io/socket.gwt.xml' on your classpath; could be a typo, or maybe you forgot to include a classpath entry for source?
```

When I add this code to GdxDefinitionSuperdev.gwt:

```
<inherits name='io.socket' />
```

When I don't, the error is:

```
> Task :html:draftCompileGwt
Compiling module com.lab.guy.GdxDefinitionSuperdev
   [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/C:/Users/Gui/Desktop/Projects/Games/TouhouIO/core/src/com/lab/guy/Touhou.java'
      [ERROR] Line 53: No source code is available for type io.socket.client.Socket; did you forget to inherit a required module?
      [ERROR] Line 177: No source code is available for type io.socket.client.IO; did you forget to inherit a required module?
      [ERROR] Line 188: No source code is available for type org.json.JSONObject; did you forget to inherit a required module?
      [ERROR] Line 204: No source code is available for type org.json.JSONException; did you forget to inherit a required module?
      [ERROR] Line 212: No source code is available for type io.socket.emitter.Emitter.Listener; did you forget to inherit a required module?
      [ERROR] Line 409: No source code is available for type org.json.JSONArray; did you forget to inherit a required module?
   Tracing compile failure path for type 'com.lab.guy.Touhou'
      [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/C:/Users/Gui/Desktop/Projects/Games/TouhouIO/core/src/com/lab/guy/Touhou.java'
         [ERROR] Line 188: No source code is available for type org.json.JSONObject; did you forget to inherit a required module?
         [ERROR] Line 204: No source code is available for type org.json.JSONException; did you forget to inherit a required module?
         [ERROR] Line 53: No source code is available for type io.socket.client.Socket; did you forget to inherit a required module?
         [ERROR] Line 177: No source code is available for type io.socket.client.IO; did you forget to inherit a required module?
         [ERROR] Line 212: No source code is available for type io.socket.emitter.Emitter.Listener; did you forget to inherit a required module?
         [ERROR] Line 409: No source code is available for type org.json.JSONArray; did you forget to inherit a required module?
      [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/C:/Users/Gui/Desktop/Projects/Games/TouhouIO/core/src/com/lab/guy/Player.java'
         [ERROR] com.lab.guy.Touhou cannot be resolved to a type
```

Full log with stack trace: https://pastebin.com/uT1pH0PV

**P.S.:** When compiling for Desktop, Socket.IO is properly included. It is featured in the "core" section of my build.gradle. The server I'm running is in Node.JS.

**P.P.S:** If I could just see how to make the basic LibGDX application (baglogic logo) compile for HTML with Socket.IO, I could substitute it for my code and have it work :)

Thank you for reading!

Answer (score 1):

Using GWT, it is not enough to include a javascript library and reference it from java code -- you need to define a java wrapper for the javascript API so you can access it from your java code.

For example, there is a project https://github.com/jumanor/gwt_socket.io where somebody has created a java wrapper for socket.io in GWT.

Once built, the app needs to be served by a HTTP web server, such as apache or the node.js module `serve`.  Then you can point your browser to the URL being served and run it in the browser.

Comment: I tried to use GWT Socket.IO, but I got stuck: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError when trying to run native methods. How do I tell JNI to look for the JS code?

Comment: That error sounds like you are running it in a JVM (e.g. node.js).  It must be run in a web browser.